# Diagonal of multidimensional DFT

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

If $X$ is a $n\times n$ square matrix and $F$ its Discrete Fourier Transform, is there a way to compute the diagonal $(F_{1,1},\ldots,F_{n,n})$ without explicitly computing the full DFT?

How about for higher dimensional arrays?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want only the diagonal elements? What is it's significance?

Comment: I want to compute the sums of the anti-diagonals of $X$ (i.e. sums of the form $\sum_i X_{i,k-i}$), but avoiding for loops because they are slow in Python. I've found that the entries of $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \text{diag}(\mathcal{F} X)$ gives these anti-diagonal sums, after zero-padding $X$ (though I haven't found a proof of this).

Comment: I do not know the computation time of phyton but you can get away with n dot product with a for loop by for k=1;N dot(dftmtx(k row), X(k column)) .

Comment: OK, yes that makes sense, seems like it is the best way of compute the diagonal of product of two matrices. Thanks!

After some experimenting, it seems pretty likely that Fourier transform is not the best way to compute the matrix antidiagonal sums, but I still think this is an interesting question, also to help me in understanding the Fourier transform better. I was hoping there'd be some neat/interesting "tricks" involving properties of Fourier transform -- I think I read somewhere that Fourier transform maps between diagonal and circulant matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal of a matrix product (AB) is the dot product of row's of the first matrix (A) with the corresponding column of the second matrix (B).